# 3D convex hull algorithm for small number points

Tags: c, algorithm, opencl, convex-hull

I have small number of 3D points. About +-10 points. I already know that all these points forms 3D convex hull. I need idea or algorithm which construct convex hull and returns the list of triangles, which forms the hull.

I want this algorithm perform on GPU using OpenCL, so every GPU thread will form separate small 3D convex hull. Because it will run using OpenCL, there are some limitation, no recursion, no dynamic memory and etc.

Comment: Finding a 3D convex hull is not trivial, but you can examine them in permuted sets of 3 points to form triangles (which for a small number of points is feasible). If every other point lies on the same side of the plane defined by the triangle, then it is a bounding triangle.

Comment: ...and you also know which is the outer face.

Comment: Yes it may, work, it is like brute force, to check all combinations. But the complexity if i am correct is N^4. For my problem this part of algorithm is important, and it will run millions times (it is similulation), so i would like to lower the complexity of algorithm as much as posible.

Comment: The perms for 3 points out of 10 is *10! / (3! . 7!) = 120*. You can abandon each candidate as soon as one mismatch is found. And of course, you only need to do it once for any set of points.

Comment: Really i already have implemented Weather Vane suggested algorithm. The problem i am looking for faster method. I have readed incremental and gift wrapping methods. The problem with them is that they need complex datastructed, which are hard to maintain in opencl, due limitations of opencl.

Comment: Convex hull algorithm is only the part of my algorithm. The real whole problem is intersection of two convex 3d polytopes. The intersection is also convex 3d polytope. So i already done one algorithm, which is based on face clipping. Now i want to solve this problem another way, firstly find the points(that part is done), and then form the final convex 3d hull.

Comment: @Ruslan so if I get it right you got 2 meshes ? why are you destroying their conectivity info during clipping? if you preserve it you would not need convex hull. ... If you do not have it and I misunderstood you can do other approaches like find 2 most distant points `O(n^2)` then find most perpendicularly distant point to it `O(n)`  which form a triangle so now find perpendicularly most distant point to it `O(n)` that forms tetrahedron so discard all points inside it `O(n)` this whole is just `O(n^2)` and will get rid of most interior points now you just expand shape outwards

Comment: while keeping it convex ... or use the naive brute force again on the points left ... You can also enlarge the first triangle to both sides so it will create 2 merged tetrahedrons instead of one ... To keep enlarged shape convex you just test which neighboring triangles are forming non convex angles and merge them to new vertex ...